# Automation for WhatsApp group

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to automate WhatsApp to send messages to my company's WhatsApp groups, which are provided in an excel file. But unfortunately it doesn't work, it's giving an error.

> AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_id'

I want it to always run every week on the scheduled day and time. I tried several methods and failed.

```Python
contatos_df = pd.read_excel("Enviar.xlsx")
display(contatos_df)
```

---

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import urllib

navegador = webdriver.Chrome()
navegador.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")

while len(navegador.find_elements_by_id("side")) < 1:
    time.sleep(1)

# já estamos com o login feito no whatsapp web
for i, mensagem in enumerate(contatos_df['Mensagem']):
    grupo = contatos_df.loc[i, "grupo"]
    texto = urllib.parse.quote(f"Oi {grupo}! {mensagem}")
    link = f"https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone={numero}&text={texto}"
    navegador.get(link)
    while len(navegador.find_elements_by_id("side")) < 1:
        time.sleep(1)
    navegador.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(10)
```

[image: excel]

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 9
      6 navegador = webdriver.Chrome()
      7 navegador.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")
----> 9 while len(navegador.find_elements_by_id("side")) < 1:
     10     time.sleep(1)
     12 # já estamos com o login feito no whatsapp web

AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_id'

Comment: what is the while loop supposed to do?